# How to fix: Liquid Exception: Tag '{%' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm getting this output from my Jekyll website generator

> Liquid Exception: Tag '{%' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%}/

What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that you've probably made a formatting error in your template. For example:

```
{% if site.ALERT 
or site.ALERT_en %}
```

will break but

```
{% if site.ALERT or site.ALERT_en %}
```

is fine.

Comment: Thanks! This happened to a work colleague, however with the same setup it worked fine for me. Strange. Are there any settings or versions of npm/gem plugins that can effect the formatting rule? Does it specify this in the docs? I can see there examples are a single line wrapping but it doesn't specify you can't force wrap.

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue with Octopress and the solution was to follow the advice by [prigazzi](https://github.com/davidfstr/rdiscount/issues/75#issuecomment-22607869):

> The file that's causing this problem in octopress, is `category_feed.xml`, inside `_includes/custom`. You need to replace `markdownify` for `markdownize` and it works.

It did work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll may not properly tell you which included file the actual syntax error belongs in. For example, I got the same error telling me that my `_layout/base.html` had this error on line 5; but the syntax was fine: `{% include head.html %}`. The syntax of `head.html` was also fine; but it included another file (`header.html`) which had an incomplete {`%` for line that I was writing but didn't finish.

Basically... you may have to follow the breadcrumb trail until you get to your error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while updating this:

```
{%- assign img_url = product | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}
```

To this:

```
{{ product | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' }}
```

Error:

```
Liquid syntax error (line 7): Variable '{{ product | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/
```

I had to break it up into two steps. Removing the `replace` stopped the error, but moving the `replace` into the `{{ }}` tags causes it to come back.

```
{%- assign img_url = product | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}
{{ img_url }}
```